# Would it be possible to extend the DataColumn.Expression

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset, datacolumn

Could extension method be used for DataColumn.Expression to support for example the replace function ?

If yes, any sample code available somewhere ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Probably not in the way you're thinking of doing it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707897/customize-datacolumn-expression-handling-in-c)

If you don't care about the original string source you're replacing, you could iterate over each DataRow and update the column values for each item instead.

```
foreach(var row in yourDataTable.Rows)
{
    row["colName"] = row["colName"].ToString().Replace("abc", "xyz");
}
```