How to use the Custom function in the expression that adds a column in the data table
I want to use the moment of adding columns to the table in the expression part of my custom function
 Dim MyTable As New DataTable
 MyTable.Columns.Add("Name")
 MyTable.Columns.Add("Age", GetType(Integer))
 MyTable.Rows.Add("Ali", 9)
 MyTable.Rows.Add("Amir", 15)
 MyTable.Rows.Add("Mansour", 18)
'There is no problem with its standard functions, such as:IIF,Trim,Len And...
' MyTable.Columns.Add("isOk", GetType(Boolean), "IIF(Age>=10 And Age<=20,True,False)")
'But I go to the Error for the custom function
 MyTable.Columns.Add("isOk", GetType(Boolean), MyFunc(Age))  'Error

Function MyFunc(InAge) as Boolean
If InAge>=10 And InAge<=20 then
return true
else
Return False
End If
End Function


https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710701/14171304

The documentation explains everything that is supported. If what you want to do were possible, it would be specified as such in that documentation.
